# Damage Control: How do I best normalize scores from different score sets that had arbitrary maximum scores?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

My friend held a contest wherein different groups could award arbitrary amounts of points for accomplishing certain goals. The problem, of course, is that the arbitrary nature means one group awarded 50,000 points for something while another group didn't award anything over 1000 points.

Let's say we have different reward sets

Group 1: 10 pts, 50 pts, 100 pts, 500 pts, 750 pts, 5000 pts

Group 2: 100 pts, 5000 pts, 50000 pts

Group 3: 10 pts, 100 pts, 250 pts, 6000 pts

How do we normalize this to make it the most "fair" and find a single winner amongst all groups? My assumption is that it is impossible to make this entirely equitable, but I'm wondering what statistics trick will mitigate this oversight the most. Right now, I'm thinking just convert everything to percentages, then multiply by 100 or 1000 to get rid of decimals.

Comment: Personally, I (also) think that the task is all but impossible.  For example, suppose that in Group 2, $99$% of the people had $100$ pts, and $0.0001$% of the people had $50000$ pts.  Further suppose that in Group 1, $20$% of the people had $5000$ pts.

Comment: When you attempt to *normalize*, you are in effect asking (for example) : How would each of the Group 1 people have done if they instead had participated in the Group 2 contest?  Personally, if I was given this task, I would make some attempt to answer that question, perhaps by running field tests on a sample of the Group 1 people to see how they do on the Group 2 test.  Alternatively, I would take the tests to an educator with a comprehensive knowledge not only of the Group 1 and Group 2 subject matters, but also the learning habits of the pertinent students.  Ask him for speculative advice.

Comment: By the way, +1 to the question that you posed, for relevance.  Educators have been grappling for over a century with the analogous question of how to measure raw intelligence via an IQ test, where there is concern over  [1] cultural bias of the test [2] environmental bias re the home life, study habits and emotional stability of the subject [3] age bias, re measuring intelligence for someone $5$ or $15$ or $20$ or $30$.  Another example: the top $10$ chess players in the world have always been men (Judith Polgar ??).  Why is that?  Does eidetic imagery ability require testosterone?